# Can I initialize Firebase in a constructor function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wonder is it a good practice to initialize firebase in the constructor?

My understanding is that constructor gets called before render method, so it is a good place to initialize firebase, as compared to componentDidMount.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "1234567890",
            authDomain: "test.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://test.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "test",
            storageBucket: "test.test.com",
            messagingSenderId: "test",
            appId: "1234test1234"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the React docs:

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the constructor. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

and...

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.

Putting this logic inside `componentDidMount` allows you to first render the UI, and then run some heavier application logic like Firebase initialisation. Ideally, the user shouldn't have to remain in a blank state before any UI shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise  firebase in your root component, eg `index.js`.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
// ...

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('xxxx', () => App);
```

This way firebase will always be initialised in your whole project, and you skip react lifecycle possible bad behaviors